# Distance to shop long/lat

Tags: views, location

I want to create a filter where companies are able to find users within eg. 10 kilometers using users added long/lat and the company's long/lat they have added.

I am using geolocation but how am I going to go about this?

Comment: the Location module ( http://drupal.org/project/location ) has Views integration that supports this.

Comment: great thank you for your help. Just what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

As Jimajamma pointed out, the Location module along with Views will allow you to filter by distance. I am currently using zipcodes to filter by, but one could do geocoordinates as well.

Here is a step by step article on how to achieve filtering.  Although the article is a tad old, it is still relevant and can easily be adapted for drupal 7.

http://drupal.org/node/359463